# embedding an X11 widget in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, x11, opencascade

I'm working on pythonocc, which exposes the OpenCasCade API in a pythonic manner.
OCC is coupled to either the windows or X11 gui environment. 
This is somewhat problematic on OSX; I need to build [Py]Qt4 for X11, rather than Cocoa, which makes distribution much harder than it should be. Hence the following question; is it possible to embed a X11 widget in Cocoa? That would allow me to use PyQt4 / PySide for Cocoa and make things a lot easier.